# ADSF 3.0 / 2012R2 authentication fails in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, ntlm, adfs

I have a ADFS 3.0 / 2012 R2 running for testing. It's a single ADFS. So I'm working on a project in ASP.NET MVC 5 and I prefer Google Chrome for development and on Chrome works authentication with ADFS.

I have tested it on Fireworks, too. No Problem ... but with Internet Explorer.
On Chrome and Firefox I get the ADFS login page (forms authentication). On IE it's windows authentication, there should be taken my windows credentials, but I get the default login prompt and login with my user / password are not working there.

If I disable windows authentication on IE so it would work, too. But I can't disable it, because it's a internal application and to switch to windows authentication complete is no option. It's planed the supply a extranet version.

What is wrong with my ADFS or what have I to do with my application?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

AD FS in Windows Server 2012 R2, forms authentication is not enabled by default.

1. Log on to the AD FS server as an administrator.
2. Open the AD FS management console and click Authentication Policies.
3. Under Primary Authentication, Global Settings, Authentication Methods, click Edit.
4. Under Intranet, enable (check) Forms Authentication.

Comment: tried your solution but still IE does not accept my user credentials. what is wrong?